# Print a signed integer stored like a binary number

Tags: c++, types, binary, type-conversion

I am learning about how to work with binary numbers to optimize some programs, and I was reading about the process to convert a binary number to an integer. The process is the two’s complement process. Given a binary number, like 1011 0100, could be 180 or -76. It depends on the type, right? But when I want to obtain -76, I always obtain 180. I want to know how I can get -76
The code to print 180:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  uint8_t num{0b1011'0100};
  
  cout<<static_cast<int>(num);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried with int8_t, but I get the next error:

> error: narrowing conversion of ‘180’ from ‘int’ to ‘int8_t’ {aka ‘signed char’} [-Wnarrowing]
> 6 |   int8_t num{0b1011'0100};

Comment: How are you optimizing programs using binary numbers?  Usually, the numbers stored in memory are binary; decimal and hex is only used for human readability.

Comment: @ThomasMatthewsfor example, if i need to have a lot of "boolean" values verifying differents states of a lot of elements (for example in a video game). the boolean type need 1 byte (8 bits), so i was reading that i can use the  Bit manipulation with bitwise operators and bit masks to seize the bits that i don t use

Comment: @Lkx8888 For such task, you should only be using unsigned types.

Comment: It's usually faster to waste a little bit of memory and use a full byte for each boolean, so that's what most video games will do.

Comment: @Lkx8888:  You are optimizing for space not speed.  Your program will need to use binary operations in order to extra bits from the data type; that takes extra time.  Using an array of unsigned integers would be a lot faster, as the processor doesn't need to extract bits.

Comment: @cafce25 That's an incorrect generalisation. It depends entirely on what you're doing.

Comment: @eerorika yes, you are right, but  it is inevitable for me to question and be interested in these issues, it is a mixture between curiosity and a desire to learn

Comment: @ThomasMatthews oh , interesting, i will read about that too, thanks!

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Werror`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> uint8_t num{0b1011'0100}
> ```

What you have here, is a `std::uint8_t` with the value 180.

As I understand, your goal is to get the value -76 using conversions. The problem with converting to `int` is that 180 is representable in that type, so the result of the conversion will be 180.

What you can do instead, is convert to `std::int8_t`:

```
std::int8_t num_s = num; // value will be -76
```

---

You'll still face the problem that would encounter with `std::uint8_t` when inserting to standard output. Since those types are aliases of character types, they will be output as symbols, so `num_s` must also be converted to `int` just like `num` is converted in your example.